# Should there be a close reason for failure to debug

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I've seen quite a few questions closed (on SO) where the individual asking the question has not made any attempt, or do not know how to actually debug their code. Simple things like seeing if it compiles, adding break points into their JavaScript using Firebug or IE developer tools. That kind of thing.

JavaScript debugging seems to be a particular problem, possibly because it does not generally have an IDE.

So do we need a close reason to explain this and possibly highlight that we have expected some attempt to debug the code?

At the moment most of these seem to be being flagged as:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question
>   checklist

If the above too generic? Do we need a more specific reason or am I just plain wrong?

Comment: You could always accompany that close vote with a constructive comment explaining which steps to take towards a question that can be reopened.

Comment: Yes true, there are (I feel) quite a lot though. Maybe I just need to find a good question on debugging javascript to point people at that,

Comment: One reason why I mention this is I see a lot of people add the comment *"have you even attempted to debug this?"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that reason covers such questions fine.

These questions clearly show that OP lacks either any understanding of the technology or did not try to find a solution on their own, as they don't include any hint of what OP found on their own during debugging. By the way, such questions also (most of the time) qualify for a downvote.

Let's break it a little bit down:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

OP does not seem either to understand the technology or the tools used.

> Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Most of the time these questions lack all three. If you're lucky they at least tell you what they want.

Also you can always leave a custom close-reason or comment if you think the OP can be helped that way.